# Not able to to use onchange event in IE 11 using jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've a scenario where I will be selecting a value from options of a textbox, when I enter the selected value it will move to next slide. This is not working in IE. I've used keyup event, but this will not satisfy because whenever the value is type and if it matches with any value before being selected it is moving to next slide. I don't want this. I have to select a value by pressing enter.

Here is my actual onchange code

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on('change', function() {
```

key up code

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']").on('keyup',function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` event and check if key code is enter or not. Like:

```
$('#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']').on('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        //move to next slide use your code
    }
});
```

or you can use `input` event

```
$('#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCityInputField']').on('input',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        //move to next slide use your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Manwal, the e.keyCode is coming as undefined

Comment: @Nizam see at last of event handler `e` is parameter of callback function. I think you are not passing it.

Comment: I'm passing it Manwal